# Custom macOS DMG

Tags: macos, mac, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I am a System Administrator and we have just deployed around 20 Macs in our office. Now I want to create a custom macOS image and install it on the Macs.

Following are the reasons:

1. I want to block USB
2. I want to remove Wi-Fi drivers

Plus I also want to know how I can implement Group Policy in macOS.

Comment: Hi. You need to do some research and then ask a specific question when you no longer can understand.

Answer (score 2):

Apple uses this book from Peachpit Press as their official curriculum for training people to manage Macs: [macOS Support Essentials 10.12 - Apple Pro Training Series: Supporting and Troubleshooting macOS Sierra](http://www.peachpit.com/store/macOS-support-essentials-10.12-apple-pro-training-series-9780134713854)

(Huh, I'm always impressed with the quality of @GordonDavission's macOS answers here on SU. I hadn't realized he literally wrote the book.)

See also: https://help.apple.com/deployment/macos/
And: http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/
    …Especially the section on NetInstall, which covers creating and installing custom macOS images with the System Image Utility and installing them:   https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/#/apdCACEA65C-46BE-4DD2-AE2D-7CB14478C394

You can also use Disk Utility and/or the command-line `hdiutil` (hard drive image utility) and `asr` (Apple Software Restore) tools to do this kind of thing, but since you're just starting out, you should probably stick with the prescribed methods using System Image Utility (part of Apple's "macOS Server" software package, which is just $20 on the Mac App Store).

As for blocking USB, I don't know if there's a good way to do this. You can't just rip out the USB device drivers because the built-in keyboard and trackpad on Mac laptops connect into the system via internal USB.

For disabling Wi-Fi, there are probably ways to do this if you don't give people admin access to their own machines (people who are Mac users by choice are usually very Mac-savvy, very self-supporting, and generally HATE being locked out of admin access to their own machines, so consider letting anyone who selects a Mac for themselves to have admin access on their own machines).

If you want to remove built-in drivers from the system, you'll have to disable SIP (System Integrity Protection) by booting from the recovery partition by holding down Cmd-R at boot, and then open Terminal and type `csrutil disable`. Then reboot from your main macOS drive and make whatever modifications under /System that you need to make, and then boot into recovery mode again and use `csrutil enable` to turn SIP back on. SIP is a great security feature, and you really don't want to accidentally leave it disabled on your users' machines.

Comment: To disable the addition of USB keys and drives, you can either remove or unload the kernel extension IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext within the /System/Library/Extensions folder.  A good write up on this can be found at: http://www.hawkdive.com/2016/05/block-or-disable-usb-storage-devices-on.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a Mac icon on the System apps (Preview, Photos, Finder....): instead make an alias, you can tag the alias and you can change the icon of the alias. Then put the original in a folder where it is.